# Connecting ElasticSearch to Django using "django-elasticsearch-dsl" results in ConnectionError when attempting to create/rebuild index

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I am trying to call a local ES instance running on docker. I used the following instructions to setup my ES instance:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-cli-run-dev-mode

I am able to play around with my instance on Kibana at http://0.0.0.0:5601/app/dev_tools#/console. Everything works upto here.

Now I am trying to define some sample documents using django models and index them through the library; I am following the instructions here: https://django-elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#install-and-configure

First, I add pip installed and added `django_elasticsearch_dsl` to `INSTALLED_APPS`

Next, I added in settings.py:

```
ELASTICSEARCH_DSL = {
    'default': {
        'hosts': 'localhost:9200'
    },
}
```

Then I create a sample model and document that looks like this:

```
# models.py

from django.db import models

class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField()
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=[
        (1, "Sedan"),
        (2, "Truck"),
        (4, "SUV"),
    ])
```

```
# documents.py

from django_elasticsearch_dsl import Document
from django_elasticsearch_dsl.registries import registry
from .models import Car

@registry.register_document
class CarDocument(Document):
    class Index:
        # Name of the Elasticsearch index
        name = 'cars'
        # See Elasticsearch Indices API reference for available settings
        settings = {'number_of_shards': 1,
                    'number_of_replicas': 0}

    class Django:
        model = Car # The model associated with this Document

        # The fields of the model you want to be indexed in Elasticsearch
        fields = [
            'name',
            'color',
            'description',
            'type',
        ]
```

Finally, running `python3 manage.py search_index --rebuild`  results in the following connection error:

```
    raise ConnectionError("N/A", str(e), e)
elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))) caused by: ProtocolError(('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')))
```

I suspect that there might be an issue with my `ELASTICSEARCH_DSL` setup as I have not specified any config for https but the documentation does not make this clear.

How do I resolve this issue?

```
Django version: 
Django==4.0.1
django-elasticsearch-dsl==7.2.2

Python version: Python 3.9.10
```

Thanks!

Comment: Also asked this question on github with no response: https://github.com/django-es/django-elasticsearch-dsl/issues/397

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured that it was an issue with my certificate.

I needed to add some additional config param to the `ELASTICSEARCH_DSL` variable. Adding this solves the issue:

```
from elasticsearch import RequestsHttpConnection

# Elasticsearch configuration in settings.py
ELASTICSEARCH_DSL = {
    'default': {
        'hosts': 'localhost:9200',
        'use_ssl': True,
        'http_auth': ('user', 'password'),
        'ca_certs': '/path/to/cert.crt'
        'connection_class': RequestsHttpConnection
    }
}
```

See [this section](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/python-api/8.0/config.html#_verifying_server_certificates) of the elastic docs on verifying a certificate.

If you haven't setup a certificate to authenticate the connection with and just need to get something up and running quickly, you can pass `'verify_certs': False` and set `'ca_certs'` to `None`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using docker, [this reply](https://github.com/django-es/django-elasticsearch-dsl/issues/397#issuecomment-1060516417) (mentioned by @cs95) helped.

> You set 'hosts': 'localhost:9200' but you have to be sure your port is
> exposed on localhost, also if your python service is running in a
> docker as well, it has to be in same network as you elasticsearch, and
> in this case, instead of localhost, you should have the service name,
> instead of localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using django-elasticsearch-dsl, but the accepted answer didn't work for me using docker.

This is what worked:

*settings.py*

```
ELASTICSEARCH_DSL = {
    "default": {
        "hosts": "https://localhost:9200",
        "http_auth": ("user (default is `elastic`)", 
                      "password (copy it from `Password for the user`)"),
        "ssl_assert_fingerprint": "fingerprint (copy it from `HTTP CA certificate SHA-256 fingerprint`)",
    }
}
```

No need to import `RequestsHttpConnection` from `elasticsearch` (which, by the way, throws error).

example:

```
ELASTICSEARCH_DSL = {
    "default": {
        "hosts": "https://localhost:9200",
        "http_auth": ("elastic", "=Al60CnKGKq+AsFLG99A"),
        "ssl_assert_fingerprint": "15c88cc1244225c987a243172d63d25d8737hb3bec3b512bf1216lq34e595775",
    }
}
```